# How to stop infinite printing of text in terminal?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, break

I am trying to view all the houses that this [site](https://www.gharghaderi.com/house-for-sale/) has to offer. For that I used while loop to keep clicking `show_more_listings button` to show more and more results. Although I achieved that I am unable to end printing of text inside except statement in VS code terminal. I tried using break in both try and except block but doing so will not allow me to parse the whole list, meaning the button is clicked only one time and then breaks or stops. I also tried to find conditions to stop loop such as `NoSuchElementException` as well as nesting while in try block but none of that worked. Here is the code:

```
from logging import exception
from typing import Text
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
from selenium import webdriver 
PATH = "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/scripts/chromedriver.exe" #always keeps chromedriver.exe inside scripts to save hours of debugging
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH) #preety important part
driver.get("https://www.gharghaderi.com/house-for-sale/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
while(True):
       try:
          show_more_listings = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="show_more"]/button')
          show_more_listings.click()
       except:
          print("you have reached end of the list no more houses to be shown") #this keeps printing infinitely in vs code terminal
         #break, is not used here cause it prevents furthur clicking of show_more_listings to view more houses
```

Comment: did you use `break` in both blocks or only in `except` block

Comment: both I  used in try as well as except

Comment: use in `except` block only and  try once

Comment: yes I did that too but still it didn't work

Comment: try this `except NoSuchElementException:` instead of `except`

Comment: I did that too, it does not stop the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem with your code is the `While Loop`, it is an infinite loop.**

As your passing `while(True):` it will keep executing and the try-except will not allow it to break as it will handle the exception situation.

**To fix this you need to set a certain condition to break it.**

1. First create a function that will check if the **show_more** button is visible or not.

**Code:**

```
def isDisplayed():
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="show_more"]/button')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

2. We will only run the `while` loop when the `show_more` button is visible else terminating the loop.

**Code:**

```
while(isDisplayed()):
    try:
        show_more_listings = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="show_more"]/button')
        show_more_listings.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        print("you have reached end of the list no more houses to be shown")
```

**Note: I have to use the `time.sleep(3)` to allow next `load_more` button to load. Please use explicit wait etc.**

**Output: No error**

[image]

**Also reached the bottom of the page:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put a `if` block inside the `try`. Like below

```
    while True:
        try:
            nextoption = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='show_more']/button")
            if nextoption:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",nextoption)
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-300)")
                nextoption.click()
            time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

Comment: your code works absolutely fine, its  concise, short but its  well suited  for intermediate developers ..I really want to know how do you know which API to use and where to use it, how are you so good in selenium

Comment: @Recurfor - Thank you. I have been practicing Selenium from past one year and still learning.